# MySQL Query Optimization: Correct Index

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

I need help for choosing a correct index in SQL query with one `LEFT JOIN`.

I have two tables (Objects and monthly Reports):

```sql
CREATE TABLE some_objects (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ...,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
CREATE TABLE month_reports (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    some_object_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    month int(11) NOT NULL,
    year int(11) NOT NULL,
    ...,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX IDX_123 (month, year),
    INDEX IDX_456 (some_object_id),
    INDEX IDX_789 (some_object_id, month, year),
    CONSTRAINT FK_123 FOREIGN KEY (some_object_id)
    REFERENCES some_objects (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)
```

I need to select all Objects with Reports at a specific month or without them. I tried this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM some_objects so 
LEFT JOIN month_reports mr ON mr.some_object_id = so.id
WHERE
    mr.month = :month
    AND mr.year = :year
    OR mr.id IS NULL
```

`EXPLAIN` result:

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys
1   SIMPLE       so     ALL
1   SIMPLE       mr     ALL   IDX_456,IDX_789
```

`EXPLAIN` result without `OR mr.id IS NULL`:

```
id  select_type  table  type    possible_keys            key      ref
1   SIMPLE       mr     ref     IDX_123,IDX_456,IDX_789  IDX_123  const,const
1   SIMPLE       so     eq_ref  PRIMARY
```

But without `OR mr.id IS NULL` I don't get Objects without Reports!

Which other index I should add? Do I need to change the query?

P.S. Sorry for my english.

**UPD.** `ANALYZE TABLE` returns "status ok". `EXPLAIN` result with `FORCE INDEX` (10 Objects, and only one have Report):

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key      rows
1   SIMPLE       so     ALL                           10
1   SIMPLE       mr     ref   IDX_789        IDX_789  1
```

Comment: You can add `some_object_id` to the existing `IDX_123`.

Comment: @Vatev Sorry, I fixed IDX_789. It has some_object_id, month, year columns, and it's not used by MySQL-server :(

Comment: It sometimes does that when you have too few rows (add some if there are few). Try running [ANALYZE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html). If that doesn't work add `FORCE KEY(IDX_789)` to the JOIN and post the query plan. Also post the row count estimates.

Comment: @Vatev I added the update to question. Is it normal result?

Comment: That looks normal. What is the row estimate for the 1-st query plan (`SIMPLE       mr     ALL`)?

Comment: @Vatev in the first plan for `SIMPLE mr ALL` - rows: 1, for `SIMPLE so ALL` - rows: 10

Comment: Well if you only have one row in the table it makes sense not to use an index. It should work fine when you have more rows.

Comment: @Vatev thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a reformulation that *might* do what you want:

```
SELECT  so.*
    FROM  some_objects so
    LEFT JOIN  month_reports mr
          ON mr.some_object_id = so.id
          AND ( mr.month = :month  AND  mr.year = :year )
```

Note that it avoids dealing with the `IS NULL` because of the way that `LEFT` works.  However, it changes the semantics slightly by moving the `WHERE` into the `ON`.

The following reforumlation using `UNION` instead of `OR` might also work (assuming the Framework will let you do it):

```
      ( SELECT  so.*
            FROM  some_objects so
            JOIN  month_reports mr ON mr.some_object_id = so.id
            WHERE  mr.month = :month
              AND  mr.year = :year         
      )
UNION
      ( SELECT  so.*
            FROM  some_objects so
            LEFT JOIN  month_reports mr ON mr.some_object_id = so.id
            WHERE  mr.id IS NULL 
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't get what I need. I will think about how to solve my problem in another way.

Unfortunatelly, I can't use `FORCE INDEX` in my Framework. But I need to get all Objects even if they all don't have Reports.

I just wanted to optimize my SQL queries. Doing it within a single query is an unsuccessful attempt :)